# Ansible template only if file doesn't exist

Tags: ansible

I am try to only setup templates if the corresponding file doesn't exist. I currently have the following which always creates the files.

```
- name: Setup templates
  template: src={{ item }} dest={{ item | basename | regex_replace('\.j2','') }}
  with_fileglob: ../templates/*.j2
```

So if there where three templates

- t1.j2
- t2.j2
- t3.j3

and two files existed in the destination

- t1
- t3

I would only like the t2.j2 template to be run and copied over..

I've seen methods to register a variable with the state command but haven't figured out how to do that with the with_fileglob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there is a force param you can pass. That will only copy the template over if the file doesn't exist.

```
- name: Setup templates
  template: src={{ item }} dest={{ item | basename | regex_replace('\.j2','') }} force=no
  with_fileglob: ../templates/*.j2
```

Comment: Old answer, and I may be barking up the wrong tree, but shouldn't that say **force=no** to achieve what you wanted?

Comment: @tink yes, it should be force= no. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat` module to determine information about the file:

```
---

- name: File exist?
  stat: path=/tmp/not-exist
  ignore_errors: true
  register: myfile

- debug: var=myfile

- name: Setup templates
  template: src={{ item }} dest={{ item | basename | regex_replace('\.j2','') }}
  with_fileglob: ../templates/*.j2
  when: myfile.stat.exists == false

- debug: msg="Print if file exist"
  when: myfile.stat.exists == true
```

This setup will skip the last task but will execute template.

Comment: That works for one file but I'd like to have the 'Setup templates' check if each item from the file glob exists and conditionally run for that particular template if does not.

Comment: You can easily  write yor own lookup_plugin that would do what you described. In my opinion  it would be the cleanest  and most readable option.